# python appengine memcache optimization

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, djangoappengine

I am developing an api on google appengine django nonrel that will serve a lot of requests. I would like to cache repeated requests.
It is estimated that there will be some really frequent queries to the api, and I would like to be able to find out what these queries are on the fly so that I may pre-cache them. Is there a way of getting the most frequent memcache keys?

Answer (score 1):

Cache everything that might be frequent, and let Memcache's LRU policy evict items that aren't accessed frequently enough to warrant remaining in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you mean "the most frequent datastore queries", [appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) is probably what you need.

Comment: no, I meant queries to the memcache. I'll correct the question.